# SVM ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, svm

Please help me for this! I don't know why this error happened when I try input some text for detection the classification.

This is my code for training the data.
How to fix it ?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train_tfidf,y_train)

if request.method == 'POST':
    message = request.form['message']
    data = [message]
    vect = vectorizer.transform(data).toarray()
    my_prediction = clf.predict(vect)

return render_template('result.html',prediction = my_prediction)`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scikit-learn : Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype ('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779961/scikit-learn-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtype-flo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if you have nulls in your data, using `your_data.isnull().any()`.
   If you have nulls, use `your_data = your_data.dropna()`.
2. Check if your data contains inf using `np.isfinite(your_data)`. If there are inf values, you can use `your_data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` and then `your_data = your_data.dropna()` to delete them.

   Change `your_data` to any name of the dataframes you are using, f.e `X`, `y` or `X_train_tfidf`

Also, check [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32) and the one marked as possible duplicate in the post comments.

---

EDIT: Adding a sample on demand. Doing it on X and y as the most obvious thing.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Add these lines
X = X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
y = y.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
X = X.dropna()
y = y.dropna()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train_tfidf,y_train)

if request.method == 'POST':
    message = request.form['message']
    data = [message]
    vect = vectorizer.transform(data).toarray()
    my_prediction = clf.predict(vect)

return render_template('result.html',prediction = my_prediction)
```

Comment: That's the solution. Where to use it? Im sorry I still learning. Im trying following tutorial with Naive, but Im trying with SVM

Comment: Can u checks [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191634/svm-attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-lower-when-i-try) . I got error when I use pipeline.

Comment: can u help me, please! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191634/svm-attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-lower-when-i-try)