# SOLVED SVM : AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower' when I try fitting TFIDF with LinearSVC

Tags: python, numpy, flask, scikit-learn, nlp

Please help me. I got error **AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'** when I try put Pipeline code.

This is the code:

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X = X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    y = y.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    X = X.dropna()
    y = y.dropna()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
    clf = LinearSVC()
    clf.fit(X_train_tfidf,y_train)

    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer()),('clf',LinearSVC())])
    text_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['message']
        data = [message]
        vect = vectorizer.transform(data).toarray()
        my_prediction = text_clf.predict(vect)

    return render_template('result.html',prediction = my_prediction)
```

SOLVED, this is a new code to fix it in my problem.

```
   from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
   from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
   from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
        text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer()),('clf',LinearSVC())])
```

I remove CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer just it.

Comment: @usr2564301 I added traceback. Check

Comment: Try `my_prediction = text_clf.predict(vect.reshape(-1, 1))` : I guess your message is a single value

Comment: @thomask Still not working

Comment: @thomask please help me.

Comment: At a first glance, I cannot see any anomaly. May I ask why are you creating the SVC, the Tfidf transformer-vectorizer before the pipeline?

Comment: @Noki I see in the tutorial and example like that. .

Comment: @Noki This solved, I know where the wrong. Thank you

Comment: @Yota add an answer to this post with the solution :)